# Calculate the area of the figure bounded by the line D: {$(\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{y^2}{3})^4=\frac{xy}{\sqrt6}; x\ge0; y\ge0$}. Switch to appropriate CS

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

Calculate the area of the figure bounded by the line $D:\{(\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{y^2}{3})^4=\frac{xy}{\sqrt6}; x\ge0; y\ge0\}$. Switch to the appropriate coordinate system.

---

So I switched to the generalized polar coordinate system and got: $$x=\sqrt{2}\ r\cos(\theta)$$ $$y=\sqrt{3}\ r\sin(\theta)$$ and Jacobian: $$|J|=\sqrt{6}\ r.$$

Then I transformed the equation of the given curve: $$(\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{y^2}{3})^4=\frac{xy}{\sqrt6} \implies r^8=r^2\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta) \implies r^6=\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta) \implies r=\sqrt[6]{\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)}$$

Then I used double integrals to find the area of the figure $D$: $$∬dxdy = \sqrt6 ∬r\ dr\ d\theta = \sqrt6 ∫_0^\frac{\pi}{2} d\theta ∫_0^{\sqrt[6]{\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)}} r\ dr = \sqrt6 ∫_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \frac{\sqrt[3]{\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)}}{2} d\theta = ...$$

So at the last point of "..." the integral cannot be found. I've been trying to find the mistake for a while, but I can't. Could you please help me find my mistake?

Comment: yes, sorry, my bad, f(x, y) was accidentally left when I was copying the formatting of formulas. I edited the question correctly now

Comment: Where did you find this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your computations are correct, but the difficulty you are encountering in the evaluation of the last integral is because it does not have an elementary closed form antiderivative.  The definite integral can be evaluated using the beta function, which in turn is expressible as the product of gamma functions.

Recall that for $a, b$ with positive real components,

$$B(a,b) = \int_{t=0}^1 t^{a-1} (1-t)^{b-1} \, dt = \frac{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(a+b)}. \tag{1}$$

In our case $a, b$ are real-valued.  An alternative but equivalent definition to $(1)$ is

$$B(a,b) = 2 \int_{\theta = 0}^{\pi/2} \sin^{2a-1} \theta \cos^{2b-1} \theta \, d\theta, \tag{2}$$

the equivalence of which I will leave to you as an exercise.  Using $(2)$, we can easily see that the choice $a = b = 2/3$ corresponds to your integral, hence your area is

$$\frac{\sqrt{6}}{4} B(2/3, 2/3) = \sqrt{\frac{3}{8}}\frac{\Gamma(2/3)^2}{\Gamma(4/3)} \approx 1.25744. \tag{3}$$

Comment: wow, thank you so much! I discussed your answer with my teacher (since we haven't studied beta functions yet) and turns out, that the teacher made a typo and it supposed to be $(\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{y^2}{3})^2$, not $(\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{y^2}{3})^4$.
anyways thank you once more, you helped me a lot and now I even discovered beta functions which now I can learn more about :)